# canDisplayBannerAds = YES causes Sprite Kit app to crash

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, iad

Working on my first game and trying to implement ads in to it.

I've declared the following in my viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

And in my implementation file I've Got the following (used because I need landscape layout)

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{


        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"Result"];
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"background-music-aac" withExtension:@"caf"];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];

    // Configure the view.

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
      skView.showsFPS = YES;
      skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

      // Create and configure the scene.
      SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
      scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

      // Present the scene.
      [skView presentScene:scene];
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    }
}
```

However when I run the app instantly crashes (log below) - if I change self.canDisplayBannerAdds = NO; the app runs fine - I have a feeling this is ridiculously simple but I can't see it for looking - anyone got any ideas?

```
2014-02-13 22:40:20.605 SpriteKitSimpleGame[2812:70b] -[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb354c0
2014-02-13 22:40:20.608 SpriteKitSimpleGame[2812:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb354c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019fa5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0177d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01a97903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x019ea90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x019ea4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   SpriteKitSimpleGame                 0x00008169 -[ViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 729
    6   UIKit                               0x0043321a -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 278
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0178f81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0232e2ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    9   QuartzCore                          0x023220d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0232e235 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
    11  UIKit                               0x004ee613 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
    12  UIKit                               0x0040d177 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
    13  UIKit                               0x0040bd16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    14  UIKit                               0x0040bbe8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    15  UIKit                               0x0040bc70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    16  UIKit                               0x0040ad0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    17  UIKit                               0x0040ac6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    18  UIKit                               0x0040b9c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    19  UIKit                               0x0040efb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    20  UIKit                               0x004e0737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    21  UIKit                               0x00404c1c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
    22  UIKit                               0x00404d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    23  UIKit                               0x0040502d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    24  UIKit                               0x0040f89a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    25  UIKit                               0x003c2cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    26  UIKit                               0x003c73a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    27  UIKit                               0x003db87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    28  UIKit                               0x003dbde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    29  UIKit                               0x003c9025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x027b12f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x027b0e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01975d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x01975a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x019a077c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0199fac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0199f8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  UIKit                               0x003c6add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    38  UIKit                               0x003c8d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    39  SpriteKitSimpleGame                 0x0000979d main + 141
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x0310570d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: sounds like the viewcontroller's view is not a SKView but a UIBiew or subclass (the ad view?) which doesn't have a method named scene

Comment: This is in a standard UiView which then presents an SKScene at the end of setting it up. Is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: well only a SKView can present a Sprite Kit scene

Comment: Right - but my SKView presents fine (at least when I don't have the candisplaybannerads line), it's the Ad code that's providing my problem

Comment: This is the error you get: "[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" which means you're sending the 'scene' selector/message to an object of class UIView. The only place where you do that in the code above (you may also be doing it elsewhere though) is in: SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) { .... verify that the self.view is actually of class SKView. If it isn't, the error is that the self.view isn't a SKView.

Comment: It is indeed the only place in the implementation where I do that - how would I go about correcting this? I'm a bit lost :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `canDisplayBannerAdds` is set to YES, you need to use `originalContentView` on your controller to get hold of your view.

Try using the following code to get hold of your view:

```
SKView * skView = self.originalContentView;
```

Comment: this works but gives a warning, so just add `(SKView*)self.originalContentView` instead

Comment: But originalContentView returns an UIView, not SKView.