# SpriteKit - iOS 7 - iAd Integration Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, iad

I am trying to integrate iAd with my current sprite kit project.  I have scoured existing questions, most of which say adding

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

will get the ads to work.  However, every time I try one of the solutions posted, I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dbcc50'
```

In the storyboard, I have tried setting the view to SKView.  I have added the iAd framework to the project.

Here is my viewWillLayoutSubviews method:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

if(!skView.scene){
    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [Intro sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
}
```

how should I solve this problem?  Any and all suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard, with the view selected.  I think this is how to change the view's class using storyboard.  But I still get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Your `self.view` in `SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;` is NOT an `SKView` it is a `UIView`.  Hence the error message: `[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Presumably you added the `(SKView *)` typecast to get rid of an error. You should not have done so - you should have fixed the error first. I'm not a `SceneKit` expert but changing the `UIView` to the custom class `SKView` should have worked provided you have changed the correct view. First,  remove the typecast as it's confusing the issue. Second, can you show us your full Storyboard hierarchy?

Comment: @RoboticCat I have updated the image above to show the full storyboard hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not crashing due to the banner ads.  You are crashing on the line

```
skView.showsFPS = NO;
```

because self.view is a UIView not a SKView.

Edit:

This appears to be a side effect of using UIViewController's iAD category extension.  You can retrieve the SKView using the following:

```
SKView * skView = (SKView*)self.originalContentView;
```

Comment: I tried setting the view to type SKView in storyboard, but I still get the same error (see edit above)

Comment: Are you sure your code posted is in the view controller that is being shown in your storyboard?  For example if you make a default project sprite kit project in xcode the view controller and storyboard it gives you are properly set up for SKView.

Comment: i believe the candisplaybannerads flag does something behind the scenes, it seems to be replacing the skview with the adbannerview, the same question has been asked dozen times before

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that the code above is showing on the storyboard, I just used the default spritekit project.

Comment: Ahh @LearnCocos2D is correct.  This is a specific issue with adding the iAd Framework category that allows for canDisplayBannerAds.  I have updated my answer. Check this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767155/candisplaybannerads-yes-causes-sprite-kit-app-to-crash

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but now I get a UIView setPaused: Invalid argument error.  however, I never call setPaused anywhere in my project, not in any of the scenes or the view controller.  I'm really confused why it would throw an error for something I haven't called.